# Barra invertida em links antes do nome do arquivo

Tags: html

Eu estava publicando uma resposta a uma pergunta de um usuário deste site quando reparei que no HTML havia tags de imagens com o src contendo uma barra invertida antes do nome do arquivo

```
<img src="galerias\001.jpg" id="fotos">
```

Confesso que foi a primeira vez que vi algo desse tipo e não achei nenhuma publicação que me desse alguma explicação a respeito desse tipo de endereçamento no atributo src.

Isso é compatível? Alguma documentação a respeito?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que li na documentação do HTML Standard o atributo src do elemento  tem que ser uma **"URL não-vazia potencialmente cercada de espaços válida"** (valid non-empty URL potentially surrounded by spaces).

---

E o que é uma valid non-empty URL potentially surrounded by spaces?

É uma URL não vazia válida (valid non-empty URL) depois de os espaços em branco serem removidos. O que nos leva a próxima pergunta:

---

O que é uma valid non-empty URL ?

É uma string URL válida que não seja vazia. Então....

---

O que é uma string URL válida?

Agora juro que vou resumir porque tem um tanto de pormenores.
Ela pode ser relativa ou absoluta. E em ambos os casos e em todos cenários, a documentação que li cita sempre o carácter U+002F (/).

**Então a conclusão é que pode funcionar provavelmente porque o navegador na hora de interpretar a URL faz a correção automaticamente, mas não é a especificação.**

[link para documentação](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#attr-img-src)

Comment: Isso tudo eu sei, eu até reproduzi a pagina do indagador e postei no meu servidor. Rodou redondo nos cinco principais navegadores. Veja no código fonte as barras invertidas antes do nome do arquivo nos src das imagens http://kithomepage.com/sos/marlonramos.htm @Fabri Damazio

Comment: Sim eu vi e testei aqui no meu site e funcionou normalmente. Mas como escrevi não tem nada na documentação que fale sobre isso. Provavelmente é alguma correção que o próprio navegador faz na hora de interpretar a url.

Comment: A curiosidade é enorme em saber exatamente porque funciona. Acho que você tem razão em dizer que provavelmente é uma correção do navegador.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo as imagens deveriam aparecer neste seu exemplo? Aqui não apareceu, mas olhando o inspetor do Chrome, o navegador realmente troca `\` para `/` ao renderizar a imagem.

Comment: sim, como disse no meu primeiro comentário acima, rodou nos 5 navegadores. Fato esse corroborado  pelo amigo  Fabri Damazio no 1º comentário dele.  Anderson Carlos Woss, por curiosidade, qual versão que não funcionou?

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Chrome, Version 57.0.2987.133 (64-bit) em Linux

Comment: Você me deu uma boa dica, inspetor, donde se conclui que Fabri Damazio tem razão em supor que seja correção do navegador. Se ele acrescentar isso na resposta, vou eleger como aceita.

Comment: Firefox 52.0.2 (64-bit) também não abriu as imagens. Opera 44.0.2510.1449 também não.

Comment: tonces, bom evitar né.

Comment: Aliás, acho que olhei o código fonte no lugar errado. No inspetor não houve a substituição e, pelo jeito, não carrega a imagem assim. Então é bom usar só `/` mesmo.

Comment: Ele substitui na hora de interpretar e não no código em si provavelmente. Na hora de fazer o parser

Comment: Sim, mas o inspetor mostra exatamente aquilo que o navegador está mostrando em tela. Se houvesse esta substitução, o link da imagem estaria corrigido no mesmo, mas continua com a barra invertida.

Comment: Façam o seguinte teste: abram este link da uma imagem na barra do navegador: https://fabridamazio.github.io/images/face.jpg
Troquem agora a ultima barra pela barra ao contrario e ele corrigirá automaticamente. Provavelmente faça a mesma coisa na hora de interpretar as urls.

Comment: Leo mas na hora de interpretar ele deve fazer a correção assim como acontece quando por exemplo esquecemos de fechar alguma tag e mesmo assim o codigo funciona porque o navegador acaba corrigindo e fechando a tag automaticamente